# An appropriate term for the 'contamination' of a language

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

Italians, for some reason, tend to accept and use foreign terms quite easily. The foreign terms that have entered and are entering common usage are mainly from the English language. Their usage has been increasing so consistently in recent years that the main Italian language authority *l'Accademia della Crusca* has raised an official alarm regarding the 'invasion' of foreign terminology.

According to a recent study, the usage of English terms has increased by 773% in the last 8 years. *L'Accademia* has issued a petition  '[Save the Italian Language](http://www.i-siena.it/2015/02/salviamo-la-lingua-italiana-dallinvasione-inglese-vola-la-petizione/) ' and will officially ask the Italian Government, Public Administrations, Media  and Public Companies to limit their use of foreign words and favour  the Italian equivalent terms instead.

Whether  this initiative will be successful or not (I really doubt it), this phenomenon is going to continue for years.

The following is just an example of everyday ordinary speech:

> - "Domani alle nove ho un meeting col mio boss. Poi al lunch vedo la mia amica con cui faccio spinning in palestra e il pomeriggio devo chiedere alla baby-sitter di venire per il week-end." (It includes  six english terms in just two sentences)

MY QUESTION:

What is the expression that describes this phenomenon?

P.S. I not looking for a definition of how  the Italian language authority is reacting, but for a term for the  phenomenon described  which, to different extents, is present also in other languages. 
I asked this question [here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11643/what-is-a-proper-term-for-the-contamination-of-a-language) and [here](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/salviamo-la-lingua-italiana) but I have yet to receive a satisfactory answer ( Alenanno's good answer hints at 'contact and change'. Is there a more precise term?).

Comment: I liked gt1's answer [*abuso degli anglicismi*](http://italian.stackexchange.com/a/5202), which I might translate as "an overabuse of [English] loanwords". I might even call it an *invasion*, but one that Italians embrace with open arms (obviously not unanimously). Perhaps *infiltration* :) *Contamination* in English tends to carry negative connotations.

Comment: True there are Italian equivalent to *many* loanwords, but I think it's considered "hip" by the young and "internationally recognizable/known" by politicians and journalists alike. They think they belong to a clique by using words such as "welfare" and  "devolution".

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I agree on 'contamination' strong connotation. But whether the increase in usage of fereign terms is a positive or negative fact is a matter of detabe. Anyway I am just looking for an expression to describe it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - the 'hip' issue is certainly true. Could that be a linguistic fad?

Comment: "Contamination" is the term I've usually heard, when the process is viewed as damaging to the "receiving" language.  One might investigate the terminology used in Iceland, which is particularly defensive of its language.  (Of course, English does not currently have this problem to any significant degree, since it's the one doing the contaminating.)

Comment: You might be looking for [*language contact*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_contact). But your questions suggests a _heavy language contact_.

Comment: @ermanen - yes, that is what is going on according to the report mentioned.

Comment: “Linguistic karma” comes to mind for any and all European nations that have not yet seen fit to ratify the [European Charter for Regional or Minority Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Charter_for_Regional_or_Minority_Languages). If the boot fits …

Comment: @Josh61: The general term for the word you have wisely put in scare quotes here (because _contamination_ is a judgement, not a description) is [***Language Contact***](http://cryptm.org/~nort/linguistics/Language%20Contact.pdf). Boring, I know, but that's science for you. It happens in all kinds of ways, utterance by utterance, person by person, year by year, quirk by quirk, in trillions of individual encounters over centuries. The phenomenon you're talking about is an example of _borrowing_, which is common in many languages (but not others, strangely).

Comment: @Mari-LouA: You would probly enjoy reading the Language Contact book link. I was just refreshing my memory and it's very clear, with a wealth of examples and descriptions. Sally Thomason is a colleague of mine, and she knows her stuff.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, thank you. Could you possibly be persuaded to write an answer?

Comment: If *pollution* and *contamination* are a little too laden with judgement, then perhaps ***dilution*** would suit as a being in the same vein but without quite such a negative connotation.

Comment: @Klors: Depends on the metaphor -- the most common fluid that gets metaphorically diluted by language contact is _blood_. If modern Italians feel threatened, imagine how the Etruscans, Oscans, Ostrogoths, and Lombards felt.

Comment: Japanese is quite huge on this, and the language it borrows from is also English.  Something like 10% of its vocabulary is European-derived, and probably around 90% of that is English.

Comment: @JohnLawler I wouldn't say the majority of Italians feel threatened, after all they are the first to latch onto an English expression and mold it to their own needs, the Italian language is still strong, but I think it suffers from a lack of prestige, it is hardly studied outside Italy. Whilst German, French, Spanish and Asian languages take precedence. Italian *moda* is admired but even our stylists are obsessed with English words and expressions and use them to sell their perfumes and upmarket T-shirts.

Comment: @Mari-Lou - wouldn't you say that the borrowing is significantly more prevalent among the young then the older Italians?

Comment: @JohnLawler - to call  it language contact is like calling a drug addict a 'gentleman who tends to overuse drugs'. But you are right, that probably is the term that best describes this trend. Just to give a concrete idea I write an  sentence of ordinary everyday speech: "Domani alle nove ho un meeting col mio boss. Poi al lunch vedo la mia amica con cui faccio spinning in palestra e il pomeriggio devo chiedere alla baby-sitter di venire per il week-end. "  6 English terms in a few lines. If it is a contact,  it is very strong!!!

Comment: Nu? I used to make my freshman students in etymology class pick their favorite paragraph in English and mark every word as being either native Germanic or borrowed Romance, and it always came out that it was half and half. And English borrowed a whole lot more than words. Words are like hats; they're in style or they're not, they work or they don't, you like them or you don't, and eventually you forget about them. There are far more enduring parts that get borrowed.

Comment: @HotLicks - English doesn't get words from other languages?  This is an absurd claim.  We **take** words and steal them *on purpose*, so we don't see it as a threat, but a lifestyle.   This nonsense is the kind of thing that happens once you create a language purity board, to keep their cushy job.

Comment: @Oldcat - I'm saying that **modern** English does not have this "problem" to a significant degree -- the language is not being altered significantly by outside influences.  There was a time in the past, though, where English "absorbed" easily several hundred words in a single year from French (and people in the English court were speaking mostly French).  But now other languages have the problem that many of their "native" speakers speak sentences that are half their language and half English.

Comment: you should copy and paste that sentence in your post: *"Domani alle nove ho un meeting col mio boss. Poi al lunch vedo la mia amica con cui faccio spinning in palestra e il pomeriggio devo chiedere alla baby-sitter di venire per il week-end.* That's perfect, did you make it up on the spot or is that a typical phrase churned out by critics? if it's yours, it's *geniale* :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA -     I just made it up on the spot! That's the way people speak! But Prof. Lawler was quite unimpressed by that. I don't think that native English speakers realise how strong the impact of English terminology  is in everyday speech of foreign languages like Italian , French etc.

Comment: That's why i said you should post it. Because unless you live in Italy and read the papers, watch the TV you don't realize. It is the speed which is quite scary. It's not an entirely new phenomenon, it did start about 25 years ago, so it's not overnight. Yes, *computer* has no equivalent in the Italian language, but boss is *capo* or *datore di lavoro*; lunch is *pranzo*; week-end is *fine settimana*. That sentence looks like a hybrid, no longer Italian. English doesn't have this "problem". But it's the Italians who have embraced this change, as if they're ashamed of their beautiful language.

Comment: There's no need to even translate it into English!

Comment: @Hot Licks:  As oldcat says, adopting words from other languages is a way of life for English.  You perhaps notice it more in Italian because most words are adopted from English, while English adopts from just about everybody.  Wikipedia has a nice list of Italian loan words: seems like it's next to impossible to discuss music or food without using a few :-)

Comment: @jamesqf - The thing is that most English speakers have no concept of the rate at which other languages are being "contaminated" at present.  Probably these languages are experiencing upheaval comparable to the Norman Conquest and associated "Frenchification" of English.  The affect on the nations' social structures is hard to predict, but at the very least is apt to be destabilizing in the near term.

Comment: @Hot Licks - we still are grabbing words - the Japanese words anime, manga, kawaii, and so on are in increasing use in the last few years even.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Ironically, English borrowed *capo* long ago from Italian.  They should have borrowed it back!

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I couldn't imagine saying that a sentence like "We had linguini and pasta at the restaurant" didn't look like English...even though all the nouns are borrowed!

Comment: Yes, OK. But the English words in Josh's example have been adopted in the last ten-fifteen years. The grammar is Italian, the pronunciation is at times laughable but the words are intact, there no assimilation, no "Italiansm" (if such a word exists)

Comment: *This anime is so kawaii"*, then.  I am an old fuddy duddy on a lot of things, but this language purity thing is totally alien.

Comment: @Oldcat, and "*emogi*" - but whose referring to linguistic "purity"?

Comment: @HotLicks - you claim this is due to *outside influences*.  The actual perpetrators are inside..it is Italians who are doing this, not English.  We don't make anyone borrow our words.  Again, putting it that way is basically a paranoid reaction by the language police.  If I don't like the way kids these days speak, at least I blame them and not some shadowy conspiracy.

Comment: @LittleEva - when you ask about 'contamination' of a language, the conclusion that you have an ideal of a pure, uncontaminated language is clear.

Comment: @LittleEva - that's even *more* extreme...that some loan words will destroy the entire idea of Italian-ness!

Comment: @LittleEva - hardly matters.  Any contact serves. The introduction of Italian immigrants to the US did a lot for English.  We just didn't *mind* that it happened.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22000/discussion-on-question-by-josh61-an-appropriate-term-for-the-contamination-of).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**My suggestion: linguistic colonization**. And here's why:

Some will deny that anything out of the ordinary is occurring here, and thereby refute the very question OP has presented, while others will suggest that the phenomenon OP refers to is merely the normal linguistic diffusion that has always occurred, and therefore suggest the employment of an established term, such as “adstratum”, “linguistic borrowings”, “contamination or pollution,” etc.

**"An appropriate term for the '*contamination*' of a language."** The title of the OP would suggest the need for a term equal in strength to "*contamination*" rather than a term equivalent to "normal" linguistic "borrowings."

And I would agree that the hyper-accelerated pace of today’s linguistic diffusion, and its resulting impact, is unprecedented and can best be understood by relating it to a concomitant phenomenon, that of "invasive species,” (*certainly a form of ecosystem contamination*) the term used to describe the egregious diffusion of biological species from previously indigenous habitats into novel or foreign territory. See, Wikipedia “Invasive species” [**Link**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasive_species)

Just as the invasive species phenomenon is largely driven by the exponential increase in international trade and travel resulting from the integration of modern transportation systems with modern communications technologies, so too its linguistic counterpart, which I will refer to as, "**linguistic colonization**,” is largely driven by modern technologies of mass communication (*i.e., cinema, TV, the PC, the internet, and a plethora of mobile devices*).

An "alien species" plays the biological role in the invasive species phenomena that "linguistic colonization"  plays in the linguistic contamination OP seeks to describe.

While I personally admire the term “*adstratum*” and, to a lesser degree, "*pollution*," these terms wholly fail to convey the virulence of a word such as "contamination" and are inadequate to describe the speed, force, and breadth of the global domination of English terminology that OP refers to, for example:

The following excerpt, loosely translated, is taken from the same [**LINK**](http://www.i-siena.it/2015/02/salviamo-la-lingua-italiana-dallinvasione-inglese-vola-la-petizione/) as is provided in the OP:

> [***T]he percentage of English loanwords has increased 773% in eight years***. And how could we argue against these figures when English words are used daily by the mass media, words which could easily be substituted with their Italian equivalents. We've (Italians) become so used to using these English terms that we struggle to translate them in Italian.

**The English Language in Nigeria:**

> Nigeria is a multilingual nation where English Language has acquired the status of a second language to many people, while it is a third language to others. It plays a significant role in education, politics, government administration, the judiciary, economy and legislation. English today can be regarded as the lamp with which the youths can travel through the education tunnel (Ige, 2000). It is even now being referred to as one of the major Nigerian languages (Ogundare 2004). See [**academy publishers**](http://ojs.academypublisher.com/index.php/tpls/article/viewFile/tpls0305748753/6829)

Today’s progressive technologies and the globalization of mass media are driving an phenomenon which some feel is rapidly dissolving the historical boundaries between segments of society, societies, and even nations. This is known as “cultural convergence" or "cultural homogenization.” Culture is the integrated and dynamic social system of behaviors, characteristics, customs, *language*, artifacts, and symbols that distinguish one social group from another.

> **Foundation for Endangered Languages**
>
> **The FEL manifesto**
>
> **1**. The Present Situation
>
> At this point in human history, most human languages are spoken by very few people, but *that majority of languages is about to vanish*. The most authoritative source on the languages of the world, the Ethnologue, lists nearly 7,000 living languages. Population figures for just over 6,000 show that:
>
> • 52% of languages are spoken by fewer than 10,000 people
>
> • 28% are spoken by fewer than 1,000
>
> • 83% are spoken only in single countries, and so are particularly exposed to the policies of a single government
>
> At the other end of the scale, 10 major languages, each spoken by over 109 million people, are the mother tongues of almost half of the world's population.
>   Some of the forces which threaten languages are clear: the impacts of urbanization, Westernization and *global communications grow daily, all diminishing the self-sufficiency and self-confidence of small and traditional communities*. Discriminatory policies and population movements also take their toll of languages. See, the Foundation for Endangered Languages [**Link**](http://www.ogmios.org/manifesto/index.php)

Related, of course, to this phenomena is the accompanying (*and very real*) fear of languages becoming the equivalent of *endangered species*.

> There is a general consensus that the loss of languages harms the cultural diversity of the world. Many projects are under way aimed at preventing or slowing this loss by revitalizing endangered languages and promoting education and literacy in minority languages. *Across the world many countries have enacted specific legislation aimed at protecting and stabilizing the language of indigenous speech communities*. see Wikipedia “endangered language” [**Link**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endangered_language)

Comment: Well basically it's saying The Italian language is "contaminated", and the percentage of English loanwords has increased 773% in eight years. And how could we argue against these figures when English words are used daily by the mass media, words which could easily be substituted with their Italian equivalents. We've (Italians) become so used to using these English terms that  we struggle to translate them in Italian. [rough translation] The last sentence is very rhetorical, it's asking outraged: "Is this right/fair?" Italians get a bit carried away :)

Comment: I would seriously doubt any statistics from official sources. Many axes are being ground. And if they've become Italian words, then Italians will apply Italian grammar and phonological rules to them, and their immigrant status will soon be overcome. It's as American as pizza pie, as Italian as Berlusconi.

Comment: @LittleEva: Yes, but the fates of threatened languages are up to their speakers; they can be helped, but they can't be forced. Especially young people. Sally works on Montana Salish and is part of a language revival project there; the last chapter of the book is on endangered languages.

Comment: @John Lawler - I'm not advocating a position here, John. I'm merely asserting that the current rate of linguistic diffusion is unprecedented and therefore inadequately conveyed by existing terminology. At least terminology that I'm aware of.

Comment: Well, that seems true, and I'm not pleased with language extinctions, either, but that's the case with all cultural innovations -- they change and often disappear with technology. Look at all the European cultural knowledge of farming and fighting with horses, lost except to antiquarians. Get kids to think speaking Skagit is cool, and you're over the hump. But that's not easy.

Comment: I particularly like your introduction, you put forth a strong case. *linguistic colonization* renders the idea, but will linguistics and experts understand and agree on using this coined term?

Comment: Gals :) It's just a few words. (Or is grammar invaded also?) Also, there are realms where Italian reigns, on the other hand. Music, for example. I was asked recently by a teacher whether I knew what _sprezzatura_ was. I didn't.

Comment: Actually, @anemone, I'm not really writing about the incorporation of merely a few words, but instead, of the disappearance of whole languages and the concomitant homogenization or extinction of cultures that is somewhat analogous to the current 6th biological extinction we are currently in the midst of. Seemed like an interesting alternative to "adstratum," I mean, you've already nailed down numero uno!   ;-)

Comment: I'm not criticizing your post. I like it. I'm merely remarking that vocabulary is only one layer of language. It would take more than introduction of foreign vocabulary to kill a language, IMO. It's still Italian, presumably, albeit in a different mantle.

Comment: Not allowing your language to adapt is more likely to put it on the critical list than otherwise.

Comment: I think the comparison to "invasive species" is a good one.  It's not so much the effect it has on the language per se, but rather the effect on the culture that is likely the biggest concern.  Upsetting the "culture" is upsetting the "ecosystem" in which people live, just a Asian Carp can upset the ecosystem of a US river.

Comment: @HotLicks - "invasive" connotes that the words are doing the moving. They didn't sneak into your language, your speakers took them up and used them!

Comment: @Oldcat - "Invasive species" don't move themselves either, they're carried by humans.

Comment: @HotLicks - not always.

Comment: I would roll back to version 15, maybe it's just me, but there's a little too much bold for my liking and it seems you're telling the reader what is *really, really* important. People can make up their own minds. Your intro is so persuasive (IMO) people will want to read the entire post.

Comment: much easier on the eye. :)

Comment: Thanks for your  research and your interest in the question!!! :))

Comment: My pleasure, @Josh61.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21969/discussion-on-answer-by-little-eva-an-appropriate-term-for-the-contamination-o).

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi♦ - our discussion ended 2 days ago. :-)

Answer (score 14):

According to Wikipedia, English is currently an [***adstratum***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratum_%28linguistics%29#Adstratum) to many other languages:

> The term is also used to identify systematic influences or a layer of borrowings in a given language from another language independently of whether the two languages continue coexisting as separate entities. Many modern languages have an appreciable adstratum from English due to the economic preponderance of the United States on international markets.

This is taken from the *stratum* entry, which uses no other term than ***contact*** for the language change in question. (One may disagree with some of the formulations, but I think the description of the process is apt.)

The described language change is presumably lexical, so one might go for the very simple term ***lexical borrowings***.

On that note, it is somewhat analogous (though hopefully different in scale) to the one occurring in England after the Norman conquest. The [Wikipedia entry on the language change](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Norman_language#Influence_of_Anglo-Norman_French_on_English) also uses *borrowings* for the general phenomenon; it offers ***supplantation*** in case the native word disappears entirely, and ***coexistence*** in case both words (the native and the loan) both belong to the language, as synonyms or with slight nuances in meaning.

Comment: Ironic that other languages and cultures are concerned over lexical borrowing from English, considering how heavily English does this very thing from practically every language it's ever had contact with.

Answer (score 4):

English has no official arbiter, no laws to defend it, no academy. I'm not sure if you will obtain a satisfactory answer to your question either here or at Linguistics beta. (And thank you for asking the latter, as well.)

L'Académie française has been on the job of defending the French language since [1635](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/linstitution/statuts-et-reglements), so I thought I'd go there to see what words they used to describe the "contamination" from foreign sources.

On their [mission statement](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/linstitution/les-missions), they start with

> Défense de la langue française

(I'm not about to attempt a translation, but I'm hoping this is close enough to Italian and Latin for the erudite readers to pick out key words.)

If it needs defense, then they are implying that there is an ongoing *linguistic attack*. Other bellicose terms might include *onslaught*, *breach*, *assault*, or *invasion*.

One paragraph says

> cette langue est encore en pleine évolution, très fluctuante sur certains points : verbes passant d’une conjugaison à une autre (recouvrer/recouvrir), genre des mots non fixé, morphologie flottante (hirondelle, arondelle ou erondelle), prononciation variable.

- évolution / "evolution" suggests *evolution*
- très fluctuante / "extremely fluctuating" suggests *fluctuation*
- non fixé / "not fixed" suggests *moving* or *shifting* or *instability*
- flottante / "floating" suggests *instability* or *being irresolute* or *being inconstant*

(For this and other suggestions, I will leave it to the OP to transform back to a desired form, as in *linguistic instability* or *being linguistically irresolute*.)

Its mission statement:

> La principale fonction de l’Académie sera de travailler, avec tout le soin et toute la diligence possibles, à donner des règles certaines à notre langue et à la rendre pure, éloquente et capable de traiter les arts et les sciences.

- donner des règles / "giving rules" suggests *rule-breaking* or *lawlessness* or *language without borders*
- pure / "pure" suggests *impurity* or *admixture* or *alloyed* or *adulterated*

*In bocca al lupo!*

Answer (score 2):

I'd call this an effect of *globalization*, the phenomenon of cultural integration between different nations driven by trade and communication. As one culture is exposed to another, members of the former may find elements of the latter appealing enough to replace equivalent elements in their own culture. Language is definitely included in this practice. In fact, I imagine it's the first and most drastically affected element of culture to be affected by globalization.

It's not as precise a meaning as other answers already given, but it's a nice generic alternative to add to the list.

Comment: [How English evolved into a global language](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-12017753)

Answer (score 1):

There is not really any such thing. All languages have evolved by borrowing words, creating new words, forgetting old words, etc., and none started as a 'pure' language. There's no such thing as 'language contamination' just as there is no such things as 'genetic contamination'. Leave such fantasies to Nazis and dog breeders.

Comment: Nazis???..what are you talking about...it is not about evil or good, but just a linguistic process.

Comment: What I'm saying is that 'contamination process' is a valid concept only if you assume the existence of original language 'purity'. If there's no such thing as 'purity' then there can be no such thing as 'contamination'. The reference to the Nazi fantasy of genetic purity, and the corresponding fear of genetic contamination, is an analogy.

Comment: Contamination may take place at different  stages of evolution. Purity is not the issue. Change is.

Comment: From O.P.: "the main Italian language authority l'Accademia della Crusca has raised an official alarm regarding the 'invasion' of foreign terminology."

Alarm! Fear! Contamination! We *must* install official government busybodies to maintain purity! This is *very* serious!

Comment: Yup.  English was born when Norman knights tried to pick up Saxon barmaids.  There's not a lot of purity to worry about there.

Comment: Ah, the N-word.  The gauntlet has been cast!!

Comment: we borrowed that word.

Answer (score 1):

A more general term that could be applied here is [appropriation](https://www.google.com/search?q=appropriation).

> 1. The action of taking something for one's own use, typically without the owner's permission.

In particular this is related to [Cultural Appropriation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_appropriation), where one culture will take elements of another culture and make it a part of their own.

In this case, instead of culture, it's parts of a language that are being appropriated, so you could reasonably call it 'linguistic appropriation' and be understood.

Answer (score 1):

When I was growing up in a Jewish neighborhood in Toronto, Canada, my friends and family would say that the first language is "peppered" with words, phrases and expressions from the second. That is the second language "peppered" the first. We would say "lightly peppered" when such words from the second language were small in number.

Many people I've known who speak more than one language will pepper their speech with expressions, words or phrases from one or more of the other languages they know, especially if their audience has at least a passing knowledge of the other language(s). Often, but not exclusively, it is for humour.

In Toronto, we speak mainly English with each other. As Canadians, we have at least studied French in school, so we often pepper our speech with French phrases, words or expressions; it adds a certain je ne sais quoi. Being Jewish, we also peppered or speech with Hebrew and Yiddish, but sometimes also other European languages which our parents or grandparents spoke. Today, otaku worldwide will pepper their language with some Japanese (ie: What kind of cars do little sisters ride? Nii-san!)

Pepper is a spice which is often added to foods to make the food more interesting to the palate. Unless ground extra fine, pepper leaves small, hard, black pieces in the food which, with some effort, can be picked out. Unlike salt, pepper doesn't dissolve, and can leave a gritty texture when not ground fine enough.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special name for this. It is a normal process.

At all times, languages have absorbed words from neighbouring languages in areas where the vocabulary of the neighbour was more advanced. Greeks took over knowledge and words from Semitic languages, the Romans borrowed from the Greeks, Germanic languages from Latin, and in modern times French was the language with the highest prestige for some time, then it was English. In areas as computer technology or the Internet the English vocabulary leads to borrowings. A normal process and such borrowings haven't harmed any language, on the contrary, the vocabulary was enlarged.

So I wouldn't call this phenomenon contamination. When areas with need for new words arise there is always some change in the vocabulary of a language. At first the development is a bit overheated, later on a process of normalisation begins. Some foreign words vanish, some are replaced by own coinages and some remain and are a gain.

Comment: Nice description...what is it called?

Comment: I  have never seen a  special name for it. I think it is the normal way of  vocabulary acquistion. A language takes what it can need from other languages. All languages made borrowings.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a better alternative than ***linguistic contamination***, or simply *contamination* (from your question), which is what is generally referred to by linguists as the influence of one language over another (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contamination), #3).

I'll also add ***language pollution*** as the *process* of using lexical borrowings from other languages (as well as non-formal language and slang) that causes the target language (in this case, Italian) to become 'polluted'.

This is a natural process that occurs in the vast majority of widely-spoken languages (English, Italian, Japanese, etc), and is an open question in linguistics (as well as computational linguistics).

Comment: Interesting, so contamination is not that bad word: (linguistics, etymology) The influence of one form (often from a foreign language) on the historical development of another form to which it may be related in meaning.

Comment: @Josh61 Exactly :) Like Italy, France also has *l'Académie Française* which tries to prevent this process (to an extent) by providing regulations on 'standard' language (French). However, the majority of members are literary (they write literature), and not linguists; they don't study the *process* of the language change, but rather the *result* of the change and how to ensure that their 'proper' language should be preserved. *Contamination* has existed for thousands of years, and is very widely studied by linguists in a variety of languages.

Answer (score 0):

A more specific term describing a single word or phrase borrowed from another language is [Loanword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword).

> A loanword (or loan word or loan-word) is a word borrowed from a donor language and incorporated into a recipient language without translation.

Essentially, it's when a word is taken in from one language and incorporated into another, without translating it or transforming it into a new word.  English is in particular *full* of loan words, but it happens pretty ubiquitously across languages.